# How to get the same query results displayed in both MS visual studio and listbox?

Tags: vb.net

I was trying to run a search query to give me all records specified in the where clause in ms management studio with the desired result. However when I transferred that query into my vb project there was only one record displayed on the listbox.

Sql query in ms management studio:

```
select * from tblInwardFile where org_name = 'MSW' and in_file_date_recieved like '05-Jun-19'
```

Below is my vb project:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    lstUpload.Items.Clear()
    Try
        cm = New SqlCommand("select * from tblInwardFile where org_name = 'MSW' and in_file_date_recieved like '05-Jun-19'", cn)
        dr.Close()
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            lst = lstUpload.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))
            lst.SubItems.Add(dr.Item(1))
            lst.SubItems.Add(dr.Item(2))
            lst.SubItems.Add(dr.Item(3))
            lst.SubItems.Add(dr.Item(4))
            lst.SubItems.Add(dr.Item(6))

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("File not found", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            dr.Close()
            viewUploaded()
            lowColor()
        End If
        'dr.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I would expect to see all records for the same query are displayed in the listbox. [This is a query result in ms managment studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2mV7.png)

Comment: Loop to read all of the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Read` and then testing `HasRows` makes no sense at all.  Here's how you should use those two members:

1. If there will never be more than one row, just call `Read`.  If it returns `True` then there is data to read and if it returns `False` then there is no data.  You only need an `Else` block if you want to do something specific if there is no data, e.g. notify the user.

```vb
If myDataReader.Read() Then
    'Read data here.
End If

If myOtherDataReader.Read() Then
    'Read data here.
Else
     'There is not data.
End If
```

2. If there could be more than one row then you should use a `Do` or `While` loop and use the result of `Read` as the termination condition.  As long as it is `True`, there is data to read, so terminate when it is `False`.

```vb
While myDataReader.Read()
    'Read data here.
End While
```

2A. If there could be more than one row and you want to do something specific if there is none, e.g. notify the user, use an `If...Else` block to test `HasRows` and place your loop in the `If` block.

```vb
If myDataReader.HasRows Then
    Do While myDataReader.Read()
        'Read data here.
    Loop
Else
    'There is no data.
End If
```